# Overriding the dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Config.php class

Tags: magento2, phpunit, integration-test

I want to override the

```
dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Config.php class.
```

Can anyone have an idea about how to override classes inside dev folder?